# react-router-dom doesn't redirect to the linked page, instead it shows the content of the linked page below the menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm currently trying to get my footer navmenu to work. It seemed like `react-router-dom` was the best choice for that, but I can't get it to redirect to the linked page. Instead the content of the Linked page shows up below the menu.

```
<Router>
  <div
    style={{
      textAlign: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      alignContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    <a style={{ marginRight: "10px", fontSize: "20px" }}>
      Impressum
    </a>
    <a style={{ marginRight: "10px", fontSize: "20px" }}>
      <Link to="/Datenschutz">Datenschutz</Link>
    </a>
    <a style={{ marginRight: "10px", fontSize: "20px" }}>
      Kontakt
    </a>
  </div>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/Datenschutz"
      element={<Datenschutz />}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

I recreated the issue in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-shape-rghsi7?file=/src/footer.js

Comment: You are still rendering the router and route in the `Footer` component. Where would you like the "TEST" content to be rendered?

Comment: I'd like it to redirect to the "Datenschutz" Page. Not display the content of the Page

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how the router works. The _routes_ go in the router (probably in the app component) to catch routes as they change. The _links_ should be _outside_ the router in your footer. When you click a link the router will catch the change and switch to the component/page/whatever described by that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the router and route in the `Footer` component.

Move the `Router` and routes from `Footer` into the `App` component. By promoting the `Router` higher in the ReactTree the routing context it provides is available to all the components under it. The links in the `Footer` will allow navigation to routes rendered in `App`.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Footer1 from "./footer";
import Datenschutz from "./Datenschutz";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Datenschutz" element={<Datenschutz />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer1 />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit react-router-dom-doesnt-redirect-to-the-linked-page-instead-it-shows-the-conte (forked)]

Comment: @JD You might also have some warnings about nesting an anchor `<a>` tag inside another anchor tag, this is because you nested a `Link` component in a `<a>`. In `react-router` we use only `Link` components to navigate to ***internal*** pages, save the `<a>` for ***external*** URLs you want to link to.

Comment: Thanks  @Drew Reese I'll remove that